# Using ssh in cy.exe() always get timeout error

Tags: ssh, exec, cypress

I use ssh command in cypress exec command. ssh command works properly but I get timeout error from exec()  function always.

My code is :

```js
cy.exec('ssh username@111.111.1.1  "\file.exe"')
```

Actually this code works properly and I can see that file.exe works on remote desktop but I get error on exec().

I think I have to put some options inside the ssh command like -q -w . I tried some of them but it did not work.

Could you please help me?

Comment: What exit code does `ssh` give you? Perhaps `{ failOnNonZeroExit: false }` to `cy.exec()` can solve the problem. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/exec#Choose-to-not-fail-on-non-zero-exit-and-assert-on-code-and-stderr

Comment: I tried failOnNonZeroExit this.  it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe exec is too limited in the way you can interact with the command being called, you need a programmable API rather than just configuration options.

You can try using a task instead, there is a library [node-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh) that will interface with a Cypress task.

I'm not familiar with ssh protocols, so you will have to fill in those details, but here is a basic example for Cypress task and the node-ssh library

**cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    ssh(params) {  

      const {username, host, remoteCommand} = params // destructure the argument

      const {NodeSSH} = require('node-ssh')
      const ssh = new NodeSSH()

      ssh.connect({
        host: host,
        username: username,
        privateKey: '/home/steel/.ssh/id_rsa'  // maybe parameterize this also
      })
      .then(function() {

        ssh.execCommand(remoteCommand, { cwd:'/var/www' })  
           .then(function(result) {
             console.log('STDOUT: ' + result.stdout)
             console.log('STDERR: ' + result.stderr)
           })
      })

      return null   
    },
  })
}
```

**Returning result**

The above ssh code is just from the example page of node-ssh. If you want to return the `result` value, I think this will do it.

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    ssh(params) { 
 
      const {username, host, remoteCommand} = params // destructure the argument

      // returning promise, which is awaited by Cypress
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const {NodeSSH} = require('node-ssh')
        const ssh = new NodeSSH()

        ssh.connect({   
          host: host,
          username: username,
          privateKey: '/home/steel/.ssh/id_rsa'
        })
        .then(function() {

          ssh.execCommand(remoteCommand, { cwd:'/var/www' })
            .then(function(result) {
              resolve(result)          // resolve to command result
            })
        })
      })
    },
  })
}
```

**In the test**

```js
cy.task('ssh', {username: 'username', host: '111.111.1.1', command: '\file.exe'})
  .then(result => {
    ...
  })
```

Only a single parameter is allowed for a task, so pass in an object and destructure it inside the task as shown above.

Comment: OK I will try the code you gave me But I use exec() function many times on my test sets.


ssh user@111.111.1.1  taskkill /f /im "file.exe"     I use like this . And I dont get error. It works properly. But when I try to run a file I dont get response.


just a minute ago I tried with start command like :  cy.exec('ssh username@111.111.1.1 start "\file.exe"')    and I didnt get timeout error. but file.exe didnt start.

really interesting

Comment: Yes, interesting. You can fine-tune the `node-ssh` code using a simple node script outside of Cypress, then once you have correct and consistent running, add the script code into the task.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` line in the task, because it makes it easier to await the ssh call to finish (even if you don't need `result`). `cy.exec()` is supposed to await and block, but it depends on how the called code signals end of process. It may be why sometimes `cy.exec()` works and sometimes it doesn't work.